# Is the expression `&(*some_vector.end())` well defined?

Tags: c++, pointers, undefined-behavior

Sometimes I need to convert vector iterators into pointers. I know there are several ways to do this, like `vector::data`, but I am curious about the validity of `&(*some_vector.end())`. I know dereferencing the end of vector is undefined behavior, but it seems that `&` operator does not need the value of the expression, and thus the end iterator will not be actually dereferenced in this expression. Is that correct? Or is this still undefined behavior?

Comment: `*some_vector.end()` still tries to dereference end()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `data()+end()-begin()`.

While `vector` iterators can be implemented as raw pointers, they do not have to be.  Dereferencing an iterator is undefined if it is the `end` iterator, which means in practice that iterators can be instrumented in debug to detect that case, and the compiler can legally assume that you never do it.  So the statement `&*it-&*begin() >= size()` can legally, by the standard, be treated as `false`.

While this may be funny, GCC does similar optimizations with signed overflow, where the hardware does one thing, but the compiler assumes nothing undefined happens, and it can discard whole code branches that are attempting to detect overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The precondition on dereferencing an iterator is that it is different to the end iterator. Even if all you do with the result is to take its address, it is still undefined behavior.